# Automatic driver search & update on Windows?

Tags: windows, drivers, updates

I have a Dell laptop issued by my employer, and I always find it a real pain to search for, download and maintain their drivers. It baffles me that there does not seem to be a nice way (product, website, ...) to just download the stuff you need, without hassle. The same goes for the other Windows based laptops in my direct environment.

Are there any (preferably free) automated solutions available? Or do you have a nice workflow - other than searching the manufacturers website - to help smoothing this process?

Comment: For Dell products: What's wrong just going to their support site and entering your Service Tag? Easy and customized.

Comment: Sometimes the easiest path is to use something like CPU-Z to identify the hardware and then download the drivers from the manufacturer.

Comment: Drivers do not need to be regularly and routinely updated.  If there is not a specific problem with a driver, there is no need to change it.  There are many third party driver updaters, but they tend to frequently be in error, identifying incorrect drivers, finding older drivers to replace more current ones, finding retail drivers to replace OEM drivers, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Drivermax](http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/) is <s>free and</s> the best and supports Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7/8, 64 and 32-bit.

Comment: This is just what I needed, nice and free (if you agree to upload your driver information, not an issue for me)

Comment: Not free anymore :-(  
Latest version: 5.31 (free program, paid update available)

Comment: Only allow to download 2 driver updates per day for now. I prefer SlimDriver free usage - got to byte the bullet to click download & install manually

Answer (score 3):

[Update Notifier](http://cleansofts.org/view/update-notifier.html) is one of my favorite FREEWARE programs. However, [Driver Checker](http://www.driverchecker.com/) is also a good one.

Comment: DriverChecker does seem to be the tool I was looking for, too bad it's payware to update the drivers though. Then again, a tool that scans for outdated drivers is a godsend.

Comment: Update Notifier only appears to check for software and not drivers...

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Secunia PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/). It can update drivers and other apps!

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but a very nice app, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Driver Genius](http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/Driver-Genius-Professional-2009/1068481134/1) is what I use.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SlimDrivers](https://www.slimwareutilities.com/slimdrivers.php) to update my drivers.

Comment: This is the best tool to me with awesome free usage! With paid version, the update is fully automated. In free version, we have to click manually to install updates